# Display a variable via jQuery notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications

In my program i am using this [jquery](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jnotify) plugin to show notifications in the jsp pages.

What i want is to get a value from a html table and display it in the text inside the notification, What i tried is as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() { 
            var table = document.getElementById("item");
            for (var i = 1; i<= table.rows.length; i++) {
               val=table.rows[i].cells[1].innerText;
                    if(table.rows[i].cells[10].innerHTML >= table.rows[i].cells[15].innerHTML)
                        {
                            //alert(val);
                            jNotify(
                            ' Re-order level' ,
                        {
                            autohide:false,
                            TimeShown:3000,
                            HorizontalPosition:'center'
                        });
                        }    
                }
                });
        </script>
```

the variable `val` in the code is getting alerted in a message box but not inside the `jNotify` notification. 
Please Help.

Comment: `jNotify(val, { [...] });` ?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jnotify

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/JkYzY/ @MarcinWolny I meant to OP to try that syntax.

Comment: are you sure you are using jQuery?

Comment: @TomSarduy yeah its a jQuery Plugin !!

Comment: @Priya: I mean, in your code, you can save a lot of lines and incoming bugs ;)

Comment: @TomSarduy Please can i know how to :) im a beginner

Comment: @Priya: You can start from here: http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/jquery-basics, as exercise make a `jQuery` version of your pure js code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it right:

```
                    jNotify(
                        ' Re-order level. Cell 15 value: [ '+ val +' ]',
                    {
                        autohide:false,
                        TimeShown:3000,
                        HorizontalPosition:'center'
                    });
```

will output you something like

> Re-order level. Cell 15 value: [ test ]

basically: **+** character allows you to merge strings. So you can create a notification made of both: text and a variable (or any other value). It also forces a type, avoiding lots of mistakes that relate to objects. If for some reason your val was empty then you'll get

> Re-order level. Cell 15 value: [ ]

But if that's the case you need to take a look at selector. As everything else should be working fine.

Also use [firebug net panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) to see if everything is loaded, then you may try to debug it with [firequery](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/firequery/) and [firefinder](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/firefinder-for-firebug/) (these are quite basic to use so I'll skip the explanation).